# MS Unit Tests: Forcing the unit tests to use a web.config (deployed in testsettings) rather than an app.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, mstest

Can anyone help. I have an ASP.NET application which has a web.config file so i have used the testsettings to DEPLOY the web.config to the OUT directory.

I have checked and it is there. But i can't pickup my connection string...

If i enter the connection string in a standard app.config in the unit test project then everything works.

I was trying to cut down on maintenance :-)

Hence i only have 1 connection string to update in 1 place..

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of your test setup, have the first step copy the `web.config` to `app.config`.

Comment: Hi ben, thanks for the comment. So i need to enter a batch file to do the copying in the testsettings dialog? or are you referring to something else.

Comment: Hi Martin, there is more than one way to do it. The crux of the comment is basically that you should just do it *any old how* - because any old how is good enough for this sort of purpose. Much more sophisticated answers are possible, and you may need them later, but for now - something which helps you automate your test suite *now* is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151446) and point to `Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir, "web.config")` as the mapped config file.